# Require initial setup before running spring web app

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm creating a very simple forums application.

My current problem is i want the user to be prompted with a setup page (what they'll use to set initial settings such as MySQL credentials) if the website has yet to be setup. When they attempt to go to `website.com/login`, it should redirect them to `website.com/setup` until the setup is fully finished.

Should i just use an interceptor for this, or is there an alternative? Also, if i use an interceptor, is it possible to "unregister" it when the website has been fully setup?